# Trouble accessing nested Array of Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, char

Sorry for the clunky title, English is not my first language.

I'm having issues controlling how a nested for loop is going around a list of lists.

Example: I have the letters, {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I}. They are in the 2d list like this:

```
 List<List<Character>> alphabet = new ArrayList<List<Character>>(3);
 alphabet.get(0).add('A'); 
 alphabet.get(1).add('B'); 
 alphabet.get(2).add('C'); 
 alphabet.get(0).add('D'); 
 alphabet.get(1).add('E'); 
 alphabet.get(2).add('F'); 
 alphabet.get(0).add('G'); 
 alphabet.get(1).add('H'); 
 alphabet.get(2).add('I');
```

So every 3rd letter in the alphabet goes in the same list.
I'm having a few problems making the for loop that would go through the alphabet list and reconstruct the alphabet in the correct order. Any help would be appreciated.

Which would be the best solution, to go across and get the letters in order, A then B then C then D.

Or go down each list first, get A then D then G, and when I move to the next list, slot then into the required position?

Thank you

// Rephrased

Imagine 3 lists, in a list. The 3 lists represent columns of letters.

```
alphabet = [[a, d, g, j], [b, e, h], [c, f, i]]
```

What is the best way to loop through the nested list, and reconstruct the alphabet in the correct order?

I will then put the result in a string and write it to a file.

This is my for loop.

```
for(int k = 0, i = 0; k < decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size(); k++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < decryptedtextColumns.size(); i++)
    {
        if(k <= decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size())
        {
            Character letter = decryptedtextColumns.get(i).get(k);
            decryptedtext.add(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Little unclear to me. Can you please rephrase ?

Comment: I tried my best to rephrase @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: Do you want to put the result in a list?

Comment: No I would like to put the result in a string and write it to a file @JawadLeWywadi

Comment: Fun problem. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Why in the world do you need that? Please show us your loop.

Comment: Its to solve a vigenere cipher. I have decrypted the letters but the algorithm stores the decrypted letter this way, and I need to recover them in the order I have shown above. So far I have tried the following, but I get out of bounds on the outer for loop when it check the k condition because i becomes 5 and I only have 5 lists 0-4.

Comment: for(int k = 0, i = 0; k < decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size(); k++)
  {   
   
   for(i = 0; i < decryptedtextColumns.size(); i++)
   {
    if(k <= decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size())
    {
     Character letter = decryptedtextColumns.get(i).get(k);
     decryptedtext.add(letter);
    }
   }
  }

Comment: The reasons I need to do it this way are a bit obscure and off topic. I explained it as simply as I can, I have to data structed in the way I shown above, and I need to recover the data in a way as to get {a,b,c,d,e,f} etc as output. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable. Post your code in the question, as well as the stack trace of the exception you get.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has a simple and short way to do it.

```
 List<Character> sortedAlphabets= alphabet.stream().flatMap(list->list.stream()).sorted().
                 collect(Collectors.toList());
```

produces output

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the MOD operator and do arithmetics on char.

Here is a possible solution :

```
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++){
         alphabet.get(i%3).add((char) ('A' + i));
     }
```

- You actually use the `MOD` of `i%3` to go systematically from `0` to `2` and add the value of `char` `'A' + i` each time you loop.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need a multi-dimensional form of the merge function from the mergesort algorithm.

Check out the following code at [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/Rmn9Rp).

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<List<Character>> alphabet = new ArrayList<List<Character>>(3);
        List<Character> first = new ArrayList<Character>();
        first.add('a');
        first.add('d');
        first.add('g');
        first.add('i');
        List<Character> second = new ArrayList<Character>();
        second.add('b');
        second.add('e');
        second.add('h');
        List<Character> third = new ArrayList<Character>();
        third.add('c');
        third.add('f');
        third.add('j');
        alphabet.add(first);
        alphabet.add(second);
        alphabet.add(third);

        List<Character> mergedSoFar = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); ++i) {
            List<Character> sortedLetters = alphabet.get(i);
            mergedSoFar = merge(mergedSoFar, sortedLetters);
        }
        System.out.println(mergedSoFar);
    }

    private static List<Character> merge(List<Character> left, List<Character> right) {
        List<Character> merged = new ArrayList<Character>(left.size() + right.size());
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < left.size() && j < right.size()) {
            char leftLetter = left.get(i);
            char rightLetter = right.get(j);
            int comparison = Character.compare(leftLetter, rightLetter);
            if (comparison < 0) {
                merged.add(leftLetter);
                ++i;
            } else if (comparison > 0) {
                merged.add(rightLetter);
                ++j;
            } else {
                // letters are same, add both
                merged.add(leftLetter);
                ++i;
                merged.add(rightLetter);
                ++j;
            }
        }
        while(i < left.size()) {
            merged.add(left.get(i));
            ++i;
        }
        while(j < right.size()) {
            merged.add(right.get(j));
            ++j;
        }
        return merged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working. As its a very specific thing I'm not sure how much use it will be but the general case is as explained above.

```
for(int k = 0, i = 0; k < decryptedtextColumns.get(i%5).size(); k++)
    {           
        i = 0;
        while(i < decryptedtextColumns.size() && k < decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size())
        {
            if(k <= decryptedtextColumns.get(i).size())
            {
                Character letter = decryptedtextColumns.get(i).get(k);
                decryptedtext.add(letter);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```